# Salesforce Flow Entry Condition - Formula

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I would like to ask for suggestion. The scenario is that the record will be updated if it meets the entry condition.

The entry formula condition is

```
AND (
ISCHANGED(Record.Address),
(Record.Address <> Record.CustomAddress)
)
```

It keeps returning an error in this line.
`Record.Address <> Record.CustomAddress`
Do you have any suggestion regarding an entry comparison formula between addresses (standard and custom)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are both Address-type fields, you'll need to individually compare each of the parts of the address to check if they're different. The naming convention for standard and custom address parts is a little different from each other as well.

If your standard address is `MailingAddress` and your custom one is `CustomAddress__c`, then it'd work like this to check if the standard address field parts have changed to be different from the custom address parts:

```
(ISCHANGED($Record.MailingStreet)
 && $Record.MailingStreet != $Record.CustomAddress__Street__s) ||
(ISCHANGED($Record.MailingCity)
 && $Record.MailingCity != $Record.CustomAddress__City__s)
```

etc...